# How to clean x of non alphabets or digits

Tags: data-cleaning

How can I remove every character from string except digits or alphabets?
example:

**dirty x:**

`x = as-.213sadf34-.-&¤%#`

**cleaned x:**

`x = as213sadf34`

Comment: which language?

Comment: See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Strip_a_set_of_characters_from_a_string for many implementations.

Comment: Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5) if I understood meaning of ur question correctly

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know which language your are using, I will propose the following high level way of processing:

1. Fetch all the strings you want to clean from your file
2. Use the following regex `[^\da-zA-Z]` on all your strings and replace the match by the empty string `''`